# Making a Scanimation

Tags: graphics, image-processing, image

Scanimations are also known as a barrier grid animation. These work by overlaying a screen with black (or in the gif below, red) bars separated by transparent bars.

[image]

The red bar width is an integer multiple of the transparent bars. The integer multiple gives the number of frames.

I'm trying to create one in Mathematica.

```
(* import gif*) 
gif = Import[
   "https://media4.giphy.com/media/WZrOaNjFPKT5e/200.webp?cid=\
ecf05e47w2d2du3r7sbbu16dpw2ofb5johbr11jmlap8lbth&ep=v1_gifs_search&\
rid=200.webp&ct=g"];
(* animate it *) 
ListAnimate[gif]

(* number of frames *) 
frames = Length[gif];
dimensions = ImageDimensions[gif[[1]]];
bars = 20; (*number of bars in the overlay *)
```

[image]

```
(* create overlay - create first row*)
columns = ConstantArray[0, dimensions[[1]]];
(* create spaces at to have correct number of bars *) 
columns[[;; ;; Round[dimensions[[1]]/bars]]] = 
  columns[[;; ;; Round[dimensions[[1]]/bars]]] /. {0 -> 
     1}; (* potentially need to make gaps bigger *) 
image = Table[columns, dimensions[[2]]];
overlay = Image[image]
```

[image]

But I'm struggling to now cut the original gif, such that the slices are the clear parts (offset) of the overlay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gif = Import[
   "https://media0.giphy.com/media/ZRXYymLPrOklq/giphy.gif?cid=\
ecf05e47loky7swxvxnip008410ue9phi8z4zxpkgfujmkv4&ep=v1_gifs_search&\
rid=giphy.gif&ct=g"];

gif = gif[[1 ;; 5]];
(*animate it*)
ListAnimate[gif]

(*number of frames*)
frames = Length[gif]
dimensions = ImageDimensions[gif[[1]]]
bars = 48; (* must be factor of the dimensions *) (*number of bars in \
the overlay*)
```

[image]

```
imagedata = ImageData[#, "Real32"] & /@ gif;
imagedata = imagedata[[;; , ;; , ;; , 1 ;; 3]]; (*take b&w only *) 
spacing = Round[N[dimensions[[1]]/bars]];
visiblespace = Round[spacing/frames];
blackspace = spacing - visiblespace;

image = Table[
   imagedata[[i, ;; , i ;; i + visiblespace]], {i, 1, frames, 1}];

eventualimage = 
  ConstantArray[{0, 0, 1}, {dimensions[[2]], spacing*bars}];
Table[eventualimage[[;; , 
     1 + (i - 1)*visiblespace + ((j - 1)*frames*visiblespace) ;; 
      i*visiblespace + ((j - 1)*frames*visiblespace)]] = 
   imagedata[[i, ;; , 
    1 + (i - 1)*visiblespace + ((j - 1)*frames*visiblespace) ;; 
     i*visiblespace + ((j - 1)*frames*visiblespace)]], {i, 1, frames, 
   1}, {j, 1, bars, 1}];
Image[eventualimage, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
overlayimage = 
  ConstantArray[{1, 1, 1}, {frames, dimensions[[2]], spacing*bars}];
overlayimageblack = 
  ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0}, {dimensions[[2]], spacing*bars}];

Table[overlayimage[[i, ;; , 
    visiblespace + ((j - 1)*(visiblespace + blackspace)) ;; 
     visiblespace + 
      blackspace + ((j - 1)*(visiblespace + blackspace))]] = 
   overlayimageblack[[;; , 
     visiblespace + ((j - 1)*(visiblespace + blackspace)) ;; 
      visiblespace + 
       blackspace + ((j - 1)*(visiblespace + blackspace))]], {j, 1, 
   bars, 1}, {i, 1, frames, 1}];

Image[overlayimage[[1]], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
overlays = 
  Transpose[
     RotateRight[
      Transpose[overlayimage[[#]]], (# - 1)*visiblespace]] & /@ 
   Range[frames];
overlayimages = ColorConvert[Image[#], "RGB"] & /@ overlays;
eventualimage2 = ColorConvert[Image[eventualimage], "RGB"];


animations = 
  ImageCompose[Image[eventualimage2], 
     ColorReplace[#, White -> Transparent]] & /@ overlayimages;

animation = ListAnimate[animations, ImageSize -> Large]

Export["animation.gif", animation, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]